# IBAction UIButton firing is delayed

Tags: ios, sdk, uibutton, ibaction

I have a UIButton connected to an IBAction in Interface Builder.

**The Problem:**

- The action firing and the de-highlight of the button both take a little bit to happen.

**The Facts:**

- View structure:

  - View

    - 10 Buttons (connected via UIControlEventTouchUpInside to the IBAction
    - View (Subview)

      - Gesture recognizer
      - Text Field
- The Subview has a UITapGestureRecognizer, which delaysTouchesBegan and delaysTouchesEnded both are set to NO
- The action is happening in the main thread.
- Testing a simple button (with no images or title, and only a simple NSLog), the result is the same

**The Question:**
Why are firing and the de-highlight delayed?

Comment: whats the event you are using to fire the button ?

Comment: The class has a lot of methods. But I don't think the code that matters, once a simple button with a simple NSLog also has the same issue...

Comment: What exactly do you mean, Malek?

Comment: what the event you used to detect the touch ,  UIControlEventTouchUpInside ..  UIControlEventTouchDown .. etc ?!

Comment: UIControlEventTouchUpInside
Edited the question

Comment: @NatanR. the button must activate when you touch up, so if you press the button it wont fire until u release while you are inside the button. change to touchdown to remove that delay

Comment: @LuisOscar got the same issue

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the end, I added somewhere some UIGestureRecognizer, and forgot to set delaysTouchesBegan to NO =(

Comment: Your answer and question helped me a lot. In my case, adding a double tap gesture on a view which contains buttons delays button reaction (os is waiting to be sure button tap won't become double tap)

Comment: Thanks for this. I was able to find multiple gesture recognisers causing considerable lag button's touchupinside.

Answer (score 8):

Ok I think that because of the `UITapGestureRecognizer` .. try to do the following :

1. connect an `IBOutlet` to your button.

2.assing the `UITapGestureRecognizer` delegate to your ViewController.

3.Implement this gesture delegate method in yourViewController

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer 
       shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
    return (! [yourButton pointInside:[touch locationInView:yourButton] withEvent:nil]);
}
```

This will make the tap to be recognized to your button not to the recognizer.

Comment: Edited again the question, @malek, check the view structure please.
This method is never called when the button is pressed, only when the other subview is pressed.

Comment: Ok, this is very strange, and I have no idea why and how.
**But cleaning all the build folder and the project, resolved.**

Comment: Thanks! This may not have helped @NatanR., but it was exactly what I needed.

Comment: @Malek_Jundi, just note that it's not **UITapGestureRecognizer** but **UIGestureRecognizerDelegate** instead (point 2.)...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your touch event is set the first contact of the button which would be the touch down event otherwise there will be a delay in the action until whichever other event you chose gets completed (i.e. touch up inside, touch up outside, etc).

Comment: If that doesn't do it then I'd have to know more specifics of the code to give you a winning answer.

Comment: Ok, this is very strange, and I have no idea why and how.
**But cleaning all the build folder and the project, resolved.**

Comment: Ah, glad you figured it out. I'm so used to doing that when a project doesn't work as it should that I forgot to suggest it. Basically your simulator was running on cached code.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, there was a delay on IBAction for a button that was in a custom CalloutView of an MKAnnotationView.

In the same way there is a ~0.5sec delay between pressing the MKAnnotationView and the MKAnnotationView actually being selected, there is also a delay between any other user interactions you might add as a subview of the MKAnnotationView.

The solution is to disable the native UIGestureRecognizer within MapView that is causing the delay of any MKAnnotation view selections.

This can be done with the solution on [this post:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35639388/tapping-an-mkannotation-to-select-it-is-really-slow)

Set isZoomEnabled = false within a gesture recognizer attached to the mapview on any tap, then set isZoomEnabled = false within a 0.5sec async dispatch.